# Precipitation field in OpenWeatherMap API 2.5

Tags: openweathermap, weather-api

I'm using the [Open Weather Map API](http://openweathermap.org/) for weather forecast.
Current available version is 2.5
Here is a snippet of XML

```
...
<time day="2013-09-07">
<symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d"/>
<precipitation value="2.5" type="rain"/>
<windDirection deg="8" code="N" name="North"/>
<windSpeed mps="1.16" name="Calm"/>
<temperature day="14.56" min="12.79" max="14.56" night="12.79" eve="14.56" morn="14.56"/>
<pressure unit="hPa" value="973.09"/>
<humidity value="98" unit="%"/>
<clouds value="broken clouds" all="68" unit="%"/>
</time>
...
```

Here is [the API request](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Barbastro%2C+Spain&units=metric&lang=en&mode=xml&cnt=5).

Does anyone know the unit of the field *precipitation*?

2.5 are mm of rain? perhaps a probability?

Comment: find a way to convert that data into a percentage or probability?

Comment: Just for an information. Are you using the paid service? I haven't got any precipitation values!

Answer (score 5):

Their description for [protocol of weather station data transmission](http://openweathermap.org/wiki/API/data_upload) describes data for upload in millimetres for both snow and rain. And their [JSON API v.1.0 (previous one)](http://openweathermap.org/wiki/API/1.0/JSON_API) states *Precipitation volume* i.e. **not** probability.

All in all, it is precipitation volume in mm.

Answer (score 2):

You can get precipitation probability with a forecast (not history as far as I know) from [forecast.io](http://forecast.io/)

{"time":1421080800,"precipIntensity":0.0401,"precipIntensityError":0.0099,"precipProbability":0.47,"precipType":"rain"}

Answer (score 1):

according to their API documentation (http://openweathermap.org/weather-data), this value represents rain (Precipitation) in the last 3 hours in mm (milimeters).

It would be great if rain probability was provided, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

From 2020-08-13: https://openweather.co.uk/blog/post/new-probability-precipitation-openweather-forecasts

> ... we have added the Probability of precipitation parameter to our
> weather forecasts.
>
> The meteorological definition of “probability of precipitation” is:
>
> “The chance that measurable precipitation (0.1 mm of rain or snow)
> will fall on any random point of the forecast region during the
> forecast period.” Simply put, this parameter shows the “chance of rain
> or snow” forecast.
>
> You can find information about the probability of precipitation in
> each API response in the pop field. This is available to our users in
> the following OpenWeather APIs:
>
> - One Call API – in “hourly” and “daily” parts of API response
> - Hourly Forecast 4 Days
> - Daily Forecast 16 Days
> - 5 Days / 3 Hours Forecast

Look for e.g. `hourly.pop` in "One Call API 2.5" (https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api#parameter) or the newer "One Call API 3.0" (https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3#example)

> Probability of precipitation. The values of the parameter vary between
> 0 and 1, where 0 is equal to 0%, 1 is equal to 100%